# Having trouble with classes and attributes in python

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I'm currently doing a simulation project using OOP in Python. I created a class for example called  Person , have the attributes age and name.
Afterwards I created several instances of this class and put them in a list.
In this list I want to grab the instance with the lowest age from that list, the instance with the highest age in this list, and then add and subtract 10 years respectively.
Everything that I already mentioned, I already know how to do it.

MY QUESTION:

How do I set the new values of the attribute age as the new attribute, so that every time I call **person2.age** , I get the new calculated value. Is there a way to do it automatically without everytime writing **person2.age = person_with_lowest_age.age **

In my code I need to call  **person_with_lowest_age.age**  instead of **person2.age** to get the updated value. In the long run I want  to do it in several itterations using while loop , so the list will be updated and new minimum and maximum values will be chosen everytime.
Thank youu!!!

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

# Create instances of the Person class
person1 = Person("Alice", 30)
person2 = Person("Bob", 25)
person3 = Person("Charlie", 40)

# Create a list of Person instances
people_list = [person1, person2, person3]

# Find the person with the lowest age based on the 'age' attribute
person_with_lowest_age = min(people_list, key=lambda person: person.age)
person_with_highest_age= max(people_list, key=lambda person: person.age)


# Perform calculations on the attribute (e.g., add 10 to the age)
new_age_lowest = person_with_lowest_age.age + 10
new_age_highest = person_with_highest_age.age - 10

#Update the attribute of the instance with the result of the calculations
person_with_lowest_age.age = new_age_lowest
person_with_highest_age = new_age_highest
```

Comment: Can you clarify What you want to get when calling `Person.age`? The lowest age of any person, the highest age, or something else?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. The code looks fine except the last line should be `person_with_highest_age.age = new_age_highest`.  But it's not clear what you think is wrong.

Comment: is this what you want: https://ideone.com/SMXX08

Comment: _"In my code I need to call person_with_lowest_age.age instead of Person.age to get the updated value"_ these are two quite different things. `Person.age` would be an attribute on the class itself. It would exist even without any instances of the class, but also any instances would inherit that value.  It's hard to see why that would be useful in your case.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to work. Why do you want to use `Person.age`? Can you give some example code where you use `Person.age`?

Comment: @PeterHaidar define a method that updates the age (e.g, `update_age(self, new_age)`).

Comment: `person_with_lowest_age.age += 10`. There's no link between `new_age_lowest` and the object you used to define it.

Comment: @GIZ ahh makes sense actually, so I should  add a method to update the age in the class person. Thank you !

Comment: TBH @chepner's suggestion makes more sense, defining a method for that seems unnecessary unless you want some additional logic to be performed (for example validating the new value before updating the attribute)

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for the insight, I'm kind off new to OOP soI need time wrapping my head around this topic. Basically the big picture, I'm doing a thermodynamical simulation between several gas tanks, there will be a mass flow between the tanks, and every second the pressure is calculated with respect to the new mass. when the tanks reach a certain pressure I want it to stop the process. The initial question was just a small part of the big picture so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have type errors in the last line.

```
person_with_highest_age = new_age_highest
```

should be

```
person_with_highest_age.age = new_age_highest
```

I use follow code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Person({self.name}, {self.age})"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create instances of the Person class
    person1 = Person("Alice", 30)
    person2 = Person("Bob", 25)
    person3 = Person("Charlie", 40)

    # Create a list of Person instances
    people_list = [person1, person2, person3]

    # Find the person with the lowest age based on the 'age' attribute
    person_with_lowest_age = min(people_list, key=lambda person: person.age)
    person_with_highest_age = max(people_list, key=lambda person: person.age)
    
    print(person_with_highest_age)
    print(person_with_lowest_age)

    # Perform calculations on the attribute (e.g., add 10 to the age)
    new_age_lowest = person_with_lowest_age.age + 10
    new_age_highest = person_with_highest_age.age - 10

    # Update the attribute of the instance with the result of the calculations
    person_with_lowest_age.age = new_age_lowest
    person_with_highest_age.age = new_age_highest
    print(person_with_highest_age)
    print(person_with_lowest_age)
```

get the output

```
Person(Charlie, 40)
Person(Bob, 25)
Person(Charlie, 30)
Person(Bob, 35)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `Person.age` will not work is because `age` is not a class attribute.
For age to be a class attribute then you will have to create your class like this

```
class Person:
    age: int = 20
    #rest of your code
print(Person.age) # 20
```

Then if you print `__dict__` of the Person class you will see in the mapping proxy that age is a class attribute.

```
Person.__dict__

# Person's class Mapping Proxy 
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'age': 20,
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Person' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Person' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})
```

The mapping proxy shows that `age` attribute is a class attribute an not a instance attribute.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

For your code of you get the mapping proxy then the following will result.

```
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              '__init__': <function __main__.Person.__init__(self, name, age)>,
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Person' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Person' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})
```